# Ghostscript with C# using dll

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

I want to use ghostscript to convert PDF to Images. Using Process class in C# is very simple. What I want is to use the gsdll32.lib or gsdll32.dll in C# and be able to execute the following command which works on command line using gswin32c

```
gs9.14\\bin\\gswin32c -Igs9.14\\lib;fonts -dSAFER -dNumRenderingThreads=2 -dBATCH -dUseCropBox -dNOPAUSE -sPDFPassword=\"\" -sDEVICE=png16m  -r200 -sOutputFile=\"output\"
```

Are there any wrappers available or any other way that I can use because when I simply try to add reference of the gsdll32.dll in C# project, i get the following error:

```
The reference could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accesible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You signed off IRC just before I was able to suggest that you look at [Ghostscript.NET](http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) by Josip Habjan.

Comment: I have looked into it but I couldn't find an options to save the loaded PDF as tiff image using CCITG4 compression. any idea anyone?

Comment: found my answer. basic example given [here](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/ProcessorSample.cs)